# How can I make my blog urls have words of the title in them?

Tags: urls

I just started a new blog and all the urls look like this:

```
sitename.com/?p=1
```

But how do people make the url have the title of the blog

Thanks!

Comment: That's known as 'pretty permalink'. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: enable permalinks in your wordpress settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the WordPress Codex, this is how to enable permalinks in your blog. From your admin dashboard on the left side go to Settings -> Permalinks

> In the Settings → Permalinks panel (Options → Permalinks before
>   WordPress 2.5), you can choose one of the "common" structures or enter
>   your own in the "Custom structure" field using the structure tags.
>
> Please note: You never, ever put your site url in the permalinks slot.
>   You must use one of the structure tags, or a combination of tags only.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks